# Unable to detect underlying OS using JS

Tags: javascript, browser-detection

When I see the console of my browser, even if i am using windows, it returns Linux.

```js
function detectOS() {
    const userAgent = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();

    if (userAgent.includes('win')) {
        return 'Windows';
    } else if (userAgent.includes('mac')) {
        return 'Mac';
    } else if (userAgent.includes('linux')) {
        return 'Linux';
    } else if (userAgent.includes('iphone') || userAgent.includes('ipad')) {
        return 'iOS';
    } else if (userAgent.includes('android')) {
        return 'Android';
    }
  
    return 'Unknown OS';
}
console.log(detectOS());
```

Any problem with the code or my console?

I tried to use other browser and PC, but not working!!!

Comment: Can you also share what is not working or what you're getting as output? Your code is correct. The issue maybe since some browsers or browser extensions might modify the user agent string, causing it to return incorrect information.

Comment: I am currently using windows 11, Chrome latest version, and the browser returns "Linux". Even I have another function to detect type of device (mobile, tablet or desktop) this also returns mobile while I am using desktop, I think the problem is the userAgent, what do you think??

Comment: If you `console.log(navigator.userAgent)` what does your Chrome output - I find it highly improbable that you are getting "Linux" as output of your code in a Windows Chrome browser

Comment: Actually you see neither `navigator.userAgent` not `navigator.platform` are foolproof methods for detecting the OS, as they can be spoofed or manipulated by browsers or extensions

Comment: I've turned your code into an executable snippet - added the `console.log(detectOS())` - does the code still output `Linux` for you?

Comment: It returns this, Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Nexus 5 Build/MRA58N) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/120.0.0.0 Mobile Safari/537.36, for console.log(navigator.userAgent) !!

Comment: and this is in Windows Chrome?

Comment: @ErmiyasArage Have you installed any extensions or changed your settings or used the devtools to set a different user agent string?

Comment: yes, It is chrome on win 11

Comment: Are you perhaps using your browser in mobile emulation mode? (not sure what Chrome calls it, in firefox it's Responsive Design Mode and it can emulate other devices

Comment: By the way, you'll want to check for android before linux, since android user-agent includes the word linux

Comment: @mandy8055 - in responsive design mode, userAgent changes, but not the platform :p

Comment: No,  I don't use any extensions and i don't change any thing, i mean i have also used edge and returns the same thing

Comment: @JaromandaX ryt! But is the OP using responsive design mode for running their code?

Comment: @mandy8055 - it is odd that both of his browsers on one machine, and apparently some other machine behave the same way, i.e. as if he is in responsive design mode! Though, he says "other browser" but then it's just the same pig with different lipstick - maybe he should try an actual other browser, like Firefox

Comment: yea I see, platform still returns win32 but userAgent returns the emulated devices' type, So thank you guys for you help!!! and i am going to check android before linux.

Comment: so ... you've been running in an emulated device all this time ...

Comment: I shall change my browser to firefox - yea

Comment: Why change to firefox? It too will confuse you when running in responsive design mode emulating a different device ...

Comment: they all are based on chrome, now its time to use real one !!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code should work for most cases. However, there might be instances where some browsers or browser extensions modify the user agent string, leading to incorrect information being returned. So they might not be the foolproof methods.<sup>***1***</sup> Additionally, if you are using a virtual machine, it could cause the user agent to report the host OS instead of the guest OS.

Since you mentioned that `navigator.platform` works for you, but also it is *[deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/platform)*, you can consider using another property, [`navigator.userAgentData.platform.`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/userAgentData)<sup>***2***</sup>

As pointed out by [JaromandaX](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5053002/jaromanda-x) in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77903642/unable-to-differentiate-between-windows-and-linux-when-detecting-using-js#comment137341109_77903642), you should check for Linux as the last condition, as Android is a [Linux-based](https://developer.android.com/guide/platform#:%7E:text=Android%20is%20an%20open%20source,The%20Android%20software%20stack.) operating system so there might be some conflict.

Reliably checking platform information is not a trivial task; therefore, if you are allowed to use a library, I'd recommend using one that can handle this for you. *[Platform.js](https://github.com/bestiejs/platform.js)* is a comprehensive library that can help you achieve this.<sup>***3***</sup>

```js
function detectOS() {
  // if a browser has no support for navigator.userAgentData.platform use platform as fallback
  const userAgent = (navigator.userAgentData.platform ?? navigator.platform).toLowerCase();

  if (userAgent.includes('win')) {
    return 'Windows';
  } else if (userAgent.includes('android')) {
    return 'Android';
  } else if (userAgent.includes('mac')) {
    return 'Mac';
  } else if (userAgent.includes('iphone') || userAgent.includes('ipad')) {
    return 'iOS';
  } else if (userAgent.includes('linux')) {
    return 'Linux';
  }
  return 'Unknown OS';
}

console.log(detectOS());
```

---

##### <sup>1</sup>Why neither `navigator.userAgent` nor `navigator.platform` are foolproof?

Below is a small script using `navigator.platform` which modifies the `platform` property.

```js
const codeToInject = `
  Object.defineProperty(navigator, "platform", {
    get: () => "MacIntel",
    set: (a) => {}
  });
`;
const script = document.createElement('script');
script.textContent = codeToInject;
(document.head || document.documentElement).appendChild(script);
script.remove();

console.log(navigator.platform); // will always return MacIntel
// For your case it will always print Mac which proves that it can be modified.
```

##### <sup>2</sup>Checking browser support

Since  `navigator.userAgentData` is experimental it is important to check for its [browser-support](https://caniuse.com/?search=navigator.userAgentData) is crucial.

##### <sup>3</sup>Using platform.js to detect OS:

Below is the way to use platform.js for your requirement.

```js
function detectOS() {
  const os = platform.os.family;

  if (os === 'Windows') {
    return 'Windows';
  } else if (os === 'OS X' || os === 'macOS') {
    return 'Mac';
  } else if (os === 'iOS') {
    return 'iOS';
  } else if (os === 'Android') {
    return 'Android';
  } else if (os === 'Linux') {
    return 'Linux';
  }

  return 'Unknown OS';
}

console.log(detectOS());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/platform/1.3.6/platform.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks so much!! That was very helpful and great lesson too.

Comment: I did accept it for you!

Answer (score 1):

You should use `navigator.platform` rather than `navigator.userAgent`. You can learn more about it in the [MDN Web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/platform)

**Do note that this feature has been deprecated and is no longer recommended**

```js
function detectOS() {
        const userAgent = navigator.platform.toLowerCase();

        if (userAgent.includes('win')) {
            return 'Windows';
        } else if (userAgent.includes('mac')) {
            return 'Mac';
        } else if (userAgent.includes('linux')) {
            return 'Linux';
        }
      
        return 'Unknown OS';
    }
```

Hope this solves your issue!

Comment: It does solve my problem but If it is  deprecated, then what can I do?

Comment: It is deprecated, but it works on major browsers. Look at this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/platform#browser_compatibility